# Adaptive card action button text & UI trimmed inside the MS Team Channel

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I'm having an issue where buttons and actions in ms teams adaptive cards won’t wrap text inside the action button. The button UI is completely broken even if we are applied `" full: width"` in MS Team. I know the `"Wrap: true || false"` we can add inside the adaptive card body or title of the textblock, Is there any other way to handle this type of scenario in the action button title in MS Team channel.

[image]

The following code we are using for the adaptive card implementation.

```
public static Attachment ChoiceMenu(string channelType, string text, List buttons, string subCategory = null)
{
    var menuCard = new AdaptiveCard("1.2");

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subCategory))
    {
        menuCard.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
        {
            Text = subCategory,
            Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Large,
            Wrap = true,
        });
    }

    menuCard.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
    {
        Text = text,
        Wrap = true,
    });

    foreach (var button in buttons)
    {
        var columns = new AdaptiveColumnSet();
        menuCard.Body.Add(columns);

        var userCategory = new AdaptiveColumn();
        columns.Columns.Add(userCategory);

        var actionType = new AdaptiveActionSet();
        userCategory.Items.Add(actionType);

        var submitAction = new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
        {
            Title = button,
            Id = button
        };

        if (channelType == Channels.Msteams)
        {
            submitAction.Data = new AdaptiveCardDataObjectForTeams()
            {
                MsTeams = new MsTeamsObject()
                {
                    Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                    DisplayText = button,
                    Text = button
                }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            submitAction.Data = button;
        }

        actionType.Actions.Add(submitAction);
    }

    return new Attachment()
    {
        ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
        Content = menuCard
    };
}
```

**Platform**

- Web ( MsTeams Web http://teams.microsoft.com ) Microsoft Teams
- Version 1.4.00.32771 (64-bit). It was last updated on 12/15/2021.

**Adaptive Card Version**

- 1.2

Comment: Could you please share the manifest json which you are using, so that we can try it once from our end and check for possible options?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I am using the above C# code for the template creation. Use the above code and increase the button title as much as possible then you will get the same result in english language as well.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I am passing one parameter as a List of buttons, so here you can add a long-length button name in the list. It will generate the same result in the MS Team channel or you can hardcode 'AdaptiveSubmitAction' title as the same procedure. I don't think here there is no manifest json because the adaptive card we are generating through C# and finally it's converted as an attachment then it will post using send activity.

Comment: Got it, let me check it from my end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Format cards in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html) docs,

> Cards support formatting in the text property only, not in the title
> or subtitle properties.

**Note:** The Action Button text is in the title property, This is the reason we cannot do any formatting for it. So there is no way to wrap text in the Action Button.

**Alternate Solution:**

We have changed the MS Team title of the button using the substring concatenation, hereafter the particular character will display `"..."`, So this way we can alternatively fix this issue.

```
submitAction.Title = button.Length > 50 ? string.Concat(button.Substring(0, 50), "...") : button;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

- [Github discussion](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/5004)

Answer (score -1):

Apart from using [full width property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#full-width-adaptive-card) in Adaptive card, there doesn't seem to be any way to increase the size of actionable buttons in adaptive card in order to fit the text/title properly.

```
"msteams": {
    "width": "Full"
}
```

Comment: We have tried the full width property in our code even though it also has the same issue. I have already mentioned the full width information in my thread itself. You can increase the full width and give a lengthy sentence in the button title then also you will get the same issue. Do you have any alternate solution for this fix like wrap kind of stuff? or you can consider this as any feature ?. In any case, we want to restrict the length of a text in the action button either in a wrap or in some other way.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of the fact that you were using full width property. I am afraid but there doesn't seem to be any alternate way. To put your concern you can raise user voice by following this(https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new).